# Assert that message is sent to self OCUnit

Tags: objective-c, tdd, ocunit, ocmock

I am fairly new to OCUnit and I am trying to add a Test Case to a method that looks like this:

```
- (void) processMessageBody:(XMPPMessage *)message
                   fromNick:(NSString *)nick;
{
    BOOL isEcho;

    SBEventMessage *eventMessage = [self parseMessageBody:message
                                                 fromNick:nick
                                                   isEcho:&isEcho];    
    if (isEcho)
    {
        NSString *requestID = [[message attributeForName:kSBMessageIDField] stringValue];

        [self processResponse:eventMessage
                        error:nil
                   forRequest:requestID];
    }
}
```

I have succesfully written testCases for the `parseMessageBody:fromNick:isEcho:` method, so I'm sure that that method works correctly. However I would like to test that `processResponse:error:forRequest:` is called in the correct scenario. I was thinking into maybe defining a global variable and swizziling that method so it writes like they suggest [here](http://iosunittesting.com/how-to-test-calls-to-super/#respond), but I was thinking that maybe that's too inelegant. Isn't there a way to do this using OCMock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With OCMock, you can do this with a partial mock:

```
-(void)testProcessMessageBodyCallsProcessResponse {
    // let's pretend this initializer exists
    XMPPMessage *bar = [XMPPMessage messageWithRequestId:@"baz"]; 

    Foo *processor = [[Foo alloc] init];
    id mockProcessor = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:processor];
    [[mockProcessor expect] processResponse:OCMOCK_ANY error:nil forRequest:@"baz"];

    [processor processMessageBody:bar fromNick:@"nick"];

    [mockProcessor verify];
}
```

You could also mock the call to `parseMessageBody:fromNick:isEcho:`, in which case you could verify that the correct `responseBody` is passed to `processMessageBody:fromNick:`.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass and Override Method. Define the following straight in your test file. Let's say the name of your class is Foo.

```
@interface TestFoo : Foo
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger processResponseCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SBEventMessage *processResponseEventMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id processResponseError;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *processResponseRequestID;
@end

@implementation TestFoo

- (void)processResponse:(id)eventMessage error:(id)error forRequest:(id)requestID
{
    ++_processResponseCount;
    _processResponseEventMessage = eventMessage;
    _processResponseError = error;
    _processResponseRequestID = requestID;
}

@end
```

Now in your test, create a TestFoo instead of a Foo. You can then write tests for

- How many times this method was invoked
- The arguments from the last time it was invoked

…That said, consider whether you ought to extract another class, and move this method to it. Then you could use a mocking framework like OCMock (or OCMockito) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Jon! I didn't think of subclassing